# Notepad++ regex replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have text file full of following lines:

```
F randomtext
F morerandomtext
```

what kind of regex I need so that the output would be like this:

```
randomtext,foo
morerandomtext,foo
```

so the F becomes foo and moves to the end of line.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Find:

```
F (.*)
```

Replace all with:

```
\1,foo
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add this: With Notepad++ you can find with regex and replace things in a set of files too. 
The following will find all files which has lines starting with capital F and space in D:\mydir -folder's *.txt files including subdirectories.

To open Find in Files-window in Notepad++ type Ctrl+Shift+F.

```
Find what: ^F (.*) 
Replace with: \1,foo
Filters: \1,foo
Directory: D:\mydir
Match case: Checked
In all sub-folders: Checked
Search Mode: Regular expression
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following regex, in your notepad++ file.

***Find what:*** `^\S+\s(.*)$`

***Replace with:*** `\1,foo`

***Explanation of regex:***

```
^\S+    ##Match from starting 1 or more occurrences of non-spaces here.
\s      ##Matching space here.
(.*)$   ##Creating one and only Capturing group which contains everything till the end of the value.
```