# Find and Replace with Space Inserted

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've got strings like this in a text file:

```
10.Divide using the divider at 12C. and pressure at 3.0.
11.Form into cylinders and put on boards, don't handle too much.
```

This Regex `(\d+\.)[A-Z]` correctly finds a numeric value, followed by a period, followed by a capital letter.

I want to insert a space between the period and the capital letter.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mostly there. When you wrap a regex subexpression in parentheses, you can refer to it in the "Replace" field of a find and replace operation. So...

```
Find what: (\d+.)([A-Z])
Replace with: \1 \2
```

(See similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466257/notepad-regex-replace).)

Comment: The dot is a special character in a pattern that means "any character". If you want to match a literal dot, you must escape it: `\.`

Comment: This did the trick:
Find: (\d+\.)([A-Z])
Replace \1 \2

I did not wrap the [A-Z] in parentheses before, which is why I was having trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Actually your regex is wrong:

`(\d+.)[A-Z]` matches 1-or-more occurennce of digits, follow by ANY CHARACTER. `.` in regex means any character.  The more correct one should be `\d+\.[A-Z]` (Omitted the group too as it is not required for matching.  Note that the `.` is escaped).

In order to insert space, apart from the solution provided by another answer by using 2 groups: i.e. Find `(\d+\.)([A-Z])` (note the dot fixed) and replace with `\1 \2`, you may also consider using lookaround feature:

Find `(?<=\d\.)(?=[A-Z])` and Replace with  (a single space).  This regex find a spot that is preceded with a digit and then a dot, and is followed by a capital letter.  Then we are replacing that spot with a space.  (Note that lookahead and lookbehind group is not included in the "matched" result)