# Incrementing Regex counter using Notepad++ find/replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am hoping to increment a regex expression.  It will hopefully change ~870 instances of

```
<input type="checkbox" class="a"   name="Check29"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="bpa" name="Check234"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="av"  name="Check1"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="ipa" name="Check74"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="a"   name="Check34"/>
```

(Extra spaces for readability on here)To

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="a"   name="Check1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="bpa" name="Check2"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="av"  name="Check3"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="ipa" name="Check4"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="a"   name="Check5"/>
```

Regex to find

```
<input type="checkbox"  class="([a-z]+)" name="Check[0-9]+"\/>
```

replace with

```
<input type="checkbox"  class="$1" name="Check????"\/>
```

My hope is to be able to change the ???? to an increment counter in notepad++ find and replace.  It'll save alot of headache and keep me from having to count far higher than I actually can.  I have found random posts on the topic but none seem to work.

Comment: This is not possible with Notepad++, take a programming language of your choice that offers the ability to use a function for regex replacement.

Comment: That is what i was afraid of already had a plan to do it using php but seemed cumbersome and figured it would be better to know how to do it in notepad++ directly.

Comment: Maybe a clue is to look for Notepad++ Macros. If you get a way to do variable, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466257/notepad-regex-replace) may be also helpful as well.

Comment: Also if you don't feel Notepad is power enough to you. You may think in replace it for an alternative. If this is the case, you can ask for it on [software recommendation](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions) forums. Regards.